# Linear independence and dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

$u = (1, 1, 0)$, $v = (1, 4, 1)$, $w = (r^2, 1, r^2)$, $b = (3+2r, 5+12r, 2r)$

a) For which values of $r$, is the set $(u,v,w)$ linearly independent? --> I got $r = \pm 0.5$ via ERO. Could someone just show me the matrix, so I know if I was on the right track?

b) For which values of $r$ is the vector $b$ a linear combination of $u,v,w$, and for which of these values of $r$ can be written as a linear combination in more than one way?  --> I got $r = 1$ or $-2$ but how to work out this part "or which of these values of $r$ can be written as a linear combination in more than one way?"

Thanks folks

Comment: By "ERO" do you mean elementary row operations?

Comment: Yes..I set up the matrix as (1 1 r^2; 1 4 1; 0 1 R^2)

Comment: That's the right matrix. You can also calculate its determinant, if you've learned how to do so. It works out to be $4r^2-1$. The roots agree with the values of $r$ you obtained.

Comment: Thanks so much...for (b) would the correct matrix be similar to (a) but the RHS is changed from the 0 vector to the b vector and you solve for r, is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: How did you obtain $r=1$ or $-2$? Please elaborate.

Comment: @auriga123 The set of vectors, $u,v,w$ is linearly **dependent** for $r = \frac{1}{2}$ since $4w = v$ in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the matrix A be the $3\times3$ matrix whose columns are the vectors $u, v\text{ and } w$.  Form the augmented matrix, $[A | b]$ .

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&r^2&3+2r\\1&4&1&5+12r\\0&1&r^2&2r\end{array} \right]$$

Do elementary row operations to get the left side of the augmented matrix into row echelon form.
$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&r^2 &3+2r\\1&4&1&5+12r\\0&1&r^2&2r
\end{array} \right] \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&0&3\\1&4&1&5+12r\\0&1&r^2&2r\end{array} \right] \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&0&3\\0&4&1&2+12r\\0&1&r^2&2r\end{array} \right] \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&0&3\\0&4&1&2+12r\\0&0&r^2-\frac{1}{4}&-r-\frac{1}{2}\end{array} \right]$$

The last row is the key to the whole question.

For part a) if $r^2-\frac{1}{4}=0$, the the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent and so too are the columns of the original matrix, $A$. Thus, If $r = \pm \frac{1}{2}$, the the vectors $u, v, w$ are linearly dependent. This is easily verified since in this case, $v = 4w$. The vectors are independent for any other value of $r$. Namely the vectors $u, v\text{ and } w$ are independent for any $r$ such that  $r \ne \pm \frac{1}{2}$.

For part b) we again see that if $r \ne \pm \frac{1}{2}$, the matrix $A$ is full rank and the system $Ax = b$ has a unique solution for any $b$. If, however, $r = \pm \frac{1}{2}$ the system has either infinitely many solutions or no solutions. Notice that when we do back substitution the last row says $(r^2-\frac{1}{4})x_3 = -(r+\frac{1}{2})$. If we let  $r = \frac{1}{2}$, then we get $0\,x_3 = -1$ and the system of equations is inconsistent and there is no solution. If however, we let with $r = -\frac{1}{2}$, we get $0\,x_3 = 0$ and there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much, it makes so much sense now, i had the same answer but didn't know how to give the solution.

Comment: You are very welcome. It is a very good problem. It demonstrates so much and you should make time to thoroughly understand it. Your instructor is to be commended for assigning it (and maybe he even came up with it?). I really do not understand why some folks downvoted the question.

Comment: @auriga123: I would add, make sure you can also solve simpler problems involving linear dependence/independence. This particular problem is fairly challenging for a beginner in my opinion.